# How to convert number to one type in perl

Tags: perl, numbers

I have two numbers. One income from web form and one fetched form DB.

```
my $a = 3701.12 // from DB
my $b = 3701.12 // from web form
```

when I try to operate `$a - $b` result is `-9.09494701772928e-13`
I've tried operate like this

```
my $a = int($a * 100) / 100;
my $b = int($b * 100) / 100;
```

result is `$a = 3701.11; $b = 3701.12`

How I should operate with them to get `$a - $b == 0`

Comment: Comments in Perl are with a `#`, not with `//`. The variables `$a` and `$b` are special global variables for `sort`, please don't use them.